# How to recode the columns based on condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have a bigdata to analyze that includes many rows with columns.

I would like to make a new column`('Recode_Brand')` copying `'Brand'` column based on the condition that only displays Top 10 brands and `'Others'`

Then how can I make the condition and the logic?

It will be perfect if I can use the condition as below;

```
Brand_list = ['Google', 'Apple', 'Amazon', 'Microsoft', 'Tencent', 'Facebook', 'Visa', 'McDonald's', 'Alibaba', 'AT&T']
```

I am quite new to Pandas and need your support. Highly appreciate in advance.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZOZ3q.png)

Answer (score 2):

Just use the `2018` column, for example:

```
df['Recode_Brand'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['Brand'] if row['2018'] <= 10 else 'Other', axis=1)
```

Or otherwise if you need that brands list you can do:

```
Brand_list = ["Google", "Apple", "Amazon", "Microsoft", "Tencent", "Facebook", "Visa", "McDonald's", "Alibaba", "AT&T"]
df['Recode_Brand'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['Brand'] if row['Brand'] in Brand_list else 'Other', axis=1)
```

**NB** If your string contains a `'` character as in `McDonald's`, you have to either wrap it in double quotes `"`, or to escape that character with `\'`.

Comment: @Sean Feel free to accept the answer by clicking on the tick if it solved your problem! :)

Answer (score 0):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to find `Brand` in `top10` and add a new column:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'2018':[7,8,3,12,15,16,10,9,4,5,11,1,14,2,13,6],
                   'Brand':['Google','Apple','Amazon','Microsoft','Tencent','Facebook','Visa','McDonalds','Alibaba','AT&T',
                            'IBM','Verizon','Marlboro','Coca-Cola','MasterCard','UPS']})
```

Create a new series with top 10 brands

```
top10 = df.nsmallest(10, '2018')
```

And add a new column, `Recode_Brand` if brand is in `top10` else `'Others'`

```
df['Recode_Brand'] = np.where((df['Brand'].eq(top10['Brand'])),df['Brand'],'Others')

print(df)
    2018       Brand Recode_Brand
0      7      Google       Google
1      8       Apple        Apple
2      3      Amazon       Amazon
3     12   Microsoft       Others
4     15     Tencent       Others
5     16    Facebook       Others
6     10        Visa         Visa
7      9   McDonalds    McDonalds
8      4     Alibaba      Alibaba
9      5        AT&T         AT&T
10    11         IBM       Others
11     1     Verizon      Verizon
12    14    Marlboro       Others
13     2   Coca-Cola    Coca-Cola
14    13  MasterCard       Others
15     6         UPS          UPS
```

Comment: I have a raw file that contains more than thousands rows not in order. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Answer by @UJIN works fine, for the sake of completion I have edited my answer!